# HTML, bootstrap modal, jQuerypre filled steps. when I set select option id="status" UI is broke

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

> I'm unable to debug the problem. When I set select option id="status" the popup is not in proper.
> I also used the bootstrap CDN
> This is HTML modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ã—</button>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-plus m-r-5"></i> Update Info</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <form class="form-horizontal">
                     <fieldset>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                           <label class="control-label">Next Meeting</label>
                           <input type="text" id="n_m_d" placeholder="Next Meeting" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                           <label class="control-label">Comments</label>
                           <input type="text" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                           <label class="control-label" for="">status</label>
                           <select class="form-control" id="" name="status">
                              <option selected disabled>SELECT</option>
                              <option value="active">Active</option>
                              <option value="own">Own</option>
                              <option value="lost">Lost</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group user-form-group">
                           <div class="pull-right">
                              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-add btn-sm">Update</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </fieldset>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

> This is Jquery code
> when i print `console.log(data[3]);` value to console its coming.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.editbtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#editmodal').modal('show');
    
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            console.log(data);
            console.log(data[3]);

            $('#id').val(data[1]);
            $('#n_m_d').val(data[2]);
            $('#status').val(data[3]); // This value for select input type
    });
});
```

> Table

```
<table id="dataTableExample1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                             <thead>
                                <tr class="info">
                                   <th>#</th>
                                   <th style="display:none">id</th>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                                   <th>Email</th>
                                   <th>Phone</th>
                                   <th>Description</th>
                                   <th>Amount</th>
                                   <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                             <?php
                             $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lead`";
                             $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                             $count = 1;
                             foreach ($result as $row) {
                                # code...
                             ?>
                                <tr>
                                   <td><?php echo $count++?></td>
                                   <td style="display:none"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                                   <td style="display:none"><?php echo $row['n_m_d'];?></td>
                                   <td style="display:none"><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $row['description'];?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $row['amount'];?></td>
                                   <td>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-add btn-xs editbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delt"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button>
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                          <?php }?>
                             </tbody>
                          </table>
```

> Now in Html `<select class="form-control" id="" name="status">` id is empty
> If i put id="status" `<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">` my page look like below IMAGE

[image: unaccepted modal]

[image: accepted modal]

> Please help Thank you

Comment: i didn't understood your question .. where is that table ? onclick of edit button you are showing data inside modal?  Add table code as well as in your question .

Comment: @Swati Yes now table code is added

Comment: I Tested your code and didn't found any such behaviour .Can you create a demo code ?

Comment: Hi @Swati what i found like, this behavior was happening because of some CDN urls. i need to keep those CDN. so that i created some condition it will work now . Thank you for replay.